# One of the nodes of a SPICE model is not explicitly used. What is this node connected to? (Trying to simulate VOM1271T)

Tags: spice, model

I am using the following SPICE model. In the `.SUBCKT VOM1271T`, what is `-out` connected to?

````
* VOM1271T PV MOSFET Driver with built-in turn-off SPICE MODEL
*                           LED ANODE
*                           | LED Kathode
*                           | |- Current output
*                           | |  |    + Current output
*                           | |  |    |

.SUBCKT VOM1271T            A K -out +out
XU1 A K 0 N001 VO1263
XU2 +out N001 +out 0 I-FAST_TOFF

.SUBCKT I-FAST_TOFF Iin Iout NC2 NC1
V1 Iin Iout 0
W1 NC1 NC2 V1 W1
.model W1 CSW(Ron=100K Roff=10Meg IT=1uA)
.ENDS

.SUBCKT VO1263      A K -Iout +Iout
XU1 A K N001 K IRLED1
XU2 N001 K -Iout +Iout GAIN-MOD
R1 -Iout +Iout 1Meg
* Zout of driver
.ENDS


.SUBCKT IRLED1              1 2 3 4
F1 4 3 V1 1
V1 5 2 0
D1 1 5 D1
.model D1 D(IS=1P N=1.948621 RS=1.560495 BV=6 IBV=10U CJO=18.8P VJ=0.532794 M=0.27985 EG=1.424 TT=500N)
.ends

.SUBCKT GAIN-MOD        +Iin -Iin -Iout +Iout
F1 -Iout +Iout V1 0.001
*current gain of driver
V1 +Iin -Iin 0
.backanno
.ends
**==================================================================*
* Note:
* Although models can be a useful tool in evaluating device performance,
* they cannot model exact device performance under all conditions, nor
* are they intended to replace breadboarding for final verification.
* Models provided by VISHAY Semiconductors GmbH (“Vishay”) do not represent
* all of the specifications and operating characteristics of the product to
* which the model relates. The models attempt to describe the characteristics
* of typical products. The current data sheet information for a given
* product represents the final design guideline and includes actual
* performance specifications. The accuracy, reliability and compatibility
* of models provided by Vishay are not guaranteed or warranted in any way
* and Vishay disclaims liability of any kind whatsoever, including, without
* limitation, liability for quality, performance, merchantability and fitness
* for a particular purpose arising out of the use, or inability to use a model.
* Vishay reserves the right to change models without prior notice.
* The products described herein, including the model and any results produced
* using the model, are subject to the specific disclaimers set forth at www.vishay.com/doc?91000.
**===================================================================
```
````

Comment: If you can't find it in the model (I don't see it) then it isn't used. It's valid to pass a node into a model that doesn't use it. Just rarely done -- especially in a completed model that is supposed to be used. But if you want to know why, you will have to contact those who wrote/provide it. The two +out's on the XU2 line draw my attention. And tying both ends of a V-source to the same node would seem wrong. But you will have to decide that and what to do about it.

Comment: @periblepsis Looking at the definition of the I-FAST-OFF subcircuit, the two +outs look correct.

Comment: @Hearth Perhaps so. But the fact that -out isn't used is still a standing question.

Comment: I don't see any `.ENDS` for the VOM1271T subcircuit. Is it possible you got a corrupted version of the file?

Comment: Downloaded model again just to be sure I did not override anything, nothing different. I was expecting some SPICE trickery, but now it seems the model is just incorrect.